# Question on hadoop "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "

Tags: java, hadoop

Here's my source code

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class PageRank {

public static final String MAGIC_STRING = ">>>>";
boolean overwrite = true;

PageRank(boolean overwrite){
    this.overwrite = overwrite;
}
public static class TextPair implements WritableComparable<TextPair>{
    Text x;
    int ordering;

    public TextPair(){
        x = new Text();
        ordering = 1;
    }

    public void setText(Text t, int o){
        x = t;
        ordering = o;
    }

    public void setText(String t, int o){
        x.set(t);
        ordering = o;
    }


    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        x.readFields(in);
        ordering = in.readInt();
    }


    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        x.write(out);
        out.writeInt(ordering);
    }


    public int hashCode() {
        return x.hashCode();
    }


    public int compareTo(TextPair o) {
        int x = this.x.compareTo(o.x);
        if(x==0)
            return ordering-o.ordering;
        else
            return x;
    }
}

public static class MapperA extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, TextPair, Text> {

private Text word = new Text();
Text title = new Text();
Text link = new Text();
TextPair textpair = new TextPair();

boolean start=false;
String currentTitle="";
private Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[\\s*(.+?)\\s*\\]\\]");
private Pattern titlePattern = Pattern.compile("<title>\\s*(.+?)\\s*</title>");
private Pattern pagePattern = Pattern.compile("&ltpage&gt\\s*(.+?)\\s*&lt/page&gt");


public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,  Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    int startPage=line.lastIndexOf("<title>");  

    if(startPage<0)
    {           
        Matcher matcher = linkPattern.matcher(line);                
        int n = 0;
        title.set(currentTitle);
        while(matcher.find()){
            textpair.setText(matcher.group(1), 1);
            context.write(textpair, title);
        }
        link.set(MAGIC_STRING);     
        textpair.setText(title.toString(), 0);
        context.write(textpair, link);
    } 
    else
    {           
        String result=line.trim();
        Matcher titleMatcher = titlePattern.matcher(result);            
        if(titleMatcher.find()){
            currentTitle = titleMatcher.group(1);
        }
        else
        {
            currentTitle=result;
        }               
        }    
   }
    } 

   public static class ReducerA extends Reducer<TextPair, Text, Text, Text>{
    Text aw = new Text();
    boolean valid = false;
    String last = "";

    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setup(context);
        while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
            TextPair key = context.getCurrentKey();
            Text value = context.getCurrentValue();
            if(key.ordering==0){
                last = key.x.toString();
            }
            else if(key.x.toString().equals(last)){
                context.write(key.x, value);
            }
        }
        cleanup(context);
         }
               }

  public static class MapperB extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>{
Text t = new Text();        
public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    context.write(value, key);
}
 }

   public static class ReducerB extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, PageRankRecord>{
    ArrayList<String> q = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        q.clear();
        for(Text value:values){
            q.add(value.toString());
        }

        PageRankRecord prr = new PageRankRecord();
        prr.setPageRank(1.0);

        if(q.size()>0){
            String[] a = new String[q.size()];
            q.toArray(a);

            prr.setlinks(a);
        }
        context.write(key, prr);
    }
}

public boolean roundA(Configuration conf, String inputPath, String outputPath, boolean overwrite) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException{
    if(FileSystem.get(conf).exists(new Path(outputPath))){
        if(overwrite){
            FileSystem.get(conf).delete(new Path(outputPath), true);
            System.err.println("The target file is dirty, overwriting!");
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    Job job = new Job(conf, "closure graph build round A");

    //job.setJarByClass(GraphBuilder.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MapperA.class);
    //job.setCombinerClass(RankCombiner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ReducerA.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(TextPair.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(30);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputPath));
    SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));
    return job.waitForCompletion(true);
}

public boolean roundB(Configuration conf, String inputPath, String outputPath) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException{
    if(FileSystem.get(conf).exists(new Path(outputPath))){
        if(overwrite){
            FileSystem.get(conf).delete(new Path(outputPath), true);
            System.err.println("The target file is dirty, overwriting!");
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    Job job = new Job(conf, "closure graph build round B");

    //job.setJarByClass(PageRank.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MapperB.class);
    //job.setCombinerClass(RankCombiner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ReducerB.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(PageRankRecord.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(30);

    SequenceFileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputPath));
    SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));
    return job.waitForCompletion(true);
}

public boolean build(Configuration conf, String inputPath, String outputPath) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException{

    System.err.println(inputPath);
    if(roundA(conf, inputPath, "cgb", true)){           
        return roundB(conf, "cgb", outputPath);
    }
    else
        return false;
}   

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();       
            //PageRanking.banner("ClosureGraphBuilder");
    PageRank cgb = new PageRank(true);
    cgb.build(conf, args[0], args[1]);
}


 }
```

Here's how i compile and run

```
javac -classpath hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar -d pagerank_classes PageRank.java PageRankRecord.java

jar -cvf pagerank.jar -C pagerank_classes/ .

bin/hadoop jar pagerank.jar PageRank pagerank result
```

but I am getting the following errors:

```
 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201001012025_0009_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PageRank$MapperA
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the 0.2.0 hadoop (want to use the non-deprecated classes), you can do:

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(YourMapReduceClass.class);  // <-- omitting this causes above error

    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did "PageRank$MapperA.class" end up inside that jar file? It should be in the same place as "PageRank.class".

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "--libjars pagerank.jar".  Mapper and reducer are running across machines, thus you need to distribute your jar to every machine.  "--libjars" helps to do that.

Comment: I had a similar problem only with an external jar dependency.  I needed the --libjars and the HADOOP_CLASSPATH to make it go.

Answer (score 1):

For the HADOOP_CLASSPATH you should specify the folder where the JAR file is located...

If you want to understand how the classpath works: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change your `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` variable, so that it points to the jar file.

e.g. `HADOOP_CLASSPATH=<what ever the path>/PageRank.jar` or something like that.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. HADOOP_CLASSPATH doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: It appears to be used by the driver part before the maps get distributed so you still need this for your app in cases where libraries you are using are not already in a system classpath.  But you'll also need --libjars to get it to the other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ECLIPSE for generating jar then use "Extract generated libraries into generated JAR" option.

Answer (score 0):

Though MapReduce program is parallel processing. Mapper, Combiner and Reducer class has sequence flow. Have to wait for completing each flow depends on other class so need `job.waitForCompletion(true);` But It must to set input and output path before starting Mapper, Combiner and Reducer class. [Reference](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html)

Solution for this already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38145962/3452185