# Class Not Found Exception in Mapreduce wordcount job

Tags: java, debugging, hadoop

i  am trying to run a wordcount job in hadoop.but always getting a class not found exception.I am posting the class that i wrote and the command i using to run the job

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

 public class WordCount {

 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
 } 

 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
 }

}
```

the wordcount.jar is exported to my downloads folder
And this is the command i use to run the job

```
   jeet@jeet-Vostro-2520:~/Downloads$ hadoop jar wordcount.jar org.gamma.WordCount /user/jeet/getty/gettysburg.txt /user/jeet/getty/out
```

in this case my mapreduce job is started but it is ending in the middle of the process.Printing the exception tree.

```
 14/01/27 13:16:02 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the   arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/01/27 13:16:02 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
14/01/27 13:16:02 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/01/27 13:16:02 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
14/01/27 13:16:02 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/01/27 13:16:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201401271247_0001
14/01/27 13:16:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/01/27 13:16:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201401271247_0001_m_000000_0,     Status : FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gamma.WordCount$Map
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:849)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:719)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gamma.WordCount$Map
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:802)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:847)
... 8 more

14/01/27 13:16:16 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201401271247_0001_m_000000_1,   Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gamma.WordCount$Map
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:849)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:719)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gamma.WordCount$Map
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:802)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:847)
... 8 more

  14/01/27 13:16:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201401271247_0001_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gamma.WordCount$Map
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:849)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:719)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gamma.WordCount$Map
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:802)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:847)
... 8 more

   14/01/27 13:16:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201401271247_0001
   14/01/27 13:16:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
   14/01/27 13:16:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
   14/01/27 13:16:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=20953
   14/01/27 13:16:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting    after reserving slots (ms)=0
   14/01/27 13:16:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting    after reserving slots (ms)=0
   14/01/27 13:16:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
   14/01/27 13:16:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
   14/01/27 13:16:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
   14/01/27 13:16:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1

somebody please please help i think i am very close of it
```

Comment: If you are using eclipse, click on `Link with Editor` button on left pane and then click on the `Wordcount` exception in the console. It will show you where the class is actually being linked to.

Comment: Which command did you use to generate the jar?

Comment: i am using eclipse to generate the jar

Comment: can you please list your wordcount.jar by using `jar -tf wordcount.jar`

Answer (score 22):

Try adding this

```
Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
```

Comment: This.  If you don't set the JAR, then Hadoop won't know which classes/code to put in the distributed cache.  Setting the JAR is required if you expect it to distribute the code for you.

Answer (score 4):

I also got the same issue and fixed it by removing same WordCount.class file in the same directory from where I am executing my jar. Looks like it is taking the class out side the jar. Try

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this :

`14/01/27 13:16:02 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).`

I got the same error when using CDH4.6 and it got solved after resolving the above warning.

Comment: What was your fix for the warning?

Comment: I believe I solved it with: job.setJar("MyWordCount.jar"); instead of "setJarByClass"

Comment: Thanks. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this method

> job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

before invoking the method

> job.waitForCompletion(true);

As like following:

> job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
>
> job.waitForCompletion(true);

Answer (score 1):

Use The below code for resolving this Problem.
job.setJarByClass(DriverClass.class);

Answer (score 0):

try `job.setJar("wordcount.jar");`, where wordcount.jar is the jar file that you are going to package to.
This method works for me, but NOT `setJarByClass`!

Comment: Just to add, On the contrary, `setJarByClass` worked for me. `setJar` gave me the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethod` error. I think it is something to do with the hadoop version. The version I am running is older one, 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
job.waitForCompletion(true);

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included an explanation along with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Though MapReduce program is parallel processing. Mapper, Combiner and Reducer class has sequence flow. Have to wait for completing each flow depends on other class so need `job.waitForCompletion(true);` But It must to set input and output path before starting Mapper, Combiner and Reducer class. [Reference](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html)

**Change your code like this:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
 }
```

I hope this will works.

Answer (score -1):

I got this to work using `JobConf#setJar(String)`