# Class not found in a MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I have a mapreduce job which takes an avro file as input. I export it along with all the required libraries (jar library files) into a jar file. I have 2 different clusters, one is HDInsight simulator and the other one in HDP sandbox. It works fine on the HDP sandbox but it gives me an error on the HDInsight simulator and cannot find AvroInputFormat class. I tried running the job with the -libjar option but it didn't help. Here is the error message:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroInputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getInputFormat(JobConf.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroInputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1895)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1919)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroInputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1893)
    ... 10 more
```

This looks weired because it runs fine on one cluster! Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you running the exact same Jar in two different environment and one succeeds but the other fails?

Comment: Can you show the code for setting up and launching the Job? Not sure what would cause one to succeed and the other to fail but make sure you're setting the Jar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373550/class-not-found-exception-in-mapreduce-wordcount-job