# Permission denied issue in mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have tried the below query.

```
hadoop jar /home/cloudera/workspace/para.jar word.Paras examples/wordcount /home/cloudera/Desktop/words/output
```

map reduce is started after that its showing below error. can anyone please help on this issue.

```
15/11/04 10:33:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201511040935_0008_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=cloudera, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

Do I need to change anything config file or in cloudera manager.

Comment: the query is 

hadoop jar /home/cloudera/workspace/para.jar word.Paras examples/wordcount  /home/cloudera/Desktop/words/output

Answer (score 0):

The exception suggests that you are trying to write to the HDFS root directory "/" which you (user:cloudera) does not have permission to do.

Without knowing what your specific jar does:

I guess that the last argument ("/home/cloudera/Desktop/words/output") is where you wish to place the output.

I guess this is supposed to be within HDFS where /home does not exist.

*Try to change this to somewhere where you can write, possibly "/user/cloudera/words/output"*

Comment: yes i changed the output as a hdfs location.but now class not found exception is coming. [cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop jar /home/cloudera/workspace/para.jar word.Paras examples/wordcount examples/output3; 15/11/05 10:13:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: map 0% reduce 0% 15/11/05 10:13:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201511050944_0005_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class word.Paras$Map not found. Here word is package name Paras is class name i have checked the output file is created as logs. how casn i fix this issue.  – Anbeswaran

Answer (score 0):

There are set of default directories to be created before you start using the hadoop cluster,

do, it should show you the directories

```
    $ hadoop fs -ls /
```

sample user, if you want to run as cloudera you need on hdfs

```
    /user/cloudera   -- the user running the program
    /user/hadoop     -- your hadoop file system user
    /user/mapred     -- your mapred user
    /tmp             -- temporary which needs to have permission hdfs chmod 1777
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The last argument that you are passing should be the output path of HDFS not the default file system.

As you are running with cloudera user, you can point to the `/user/cloudera/words/output`. But first you need to **check** whether you have cloudera in your HDFS and you have write permission by issuing the following

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/
```

Once you have it change your command to following:

```
hadoop jar /home/cloudera/workspace/para.jar word.Paras examples/wordcount <path_where_you_have_write_permission_in_HDFS>
```

Comment: yes i changed the output as a hdfs location.but now class not found exception is coming.

[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop jar /home/cloudera/workspace/para.jar word.Paras examples/wordcount examples/output3;

15/11/05 10:13:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/11/05 10:13:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201511050944_0005_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class word.Paras$Map not found.
Here word is package name Paras is class name i have checked the output file is created as logs. how casn i fix this issue.

Comment: looks like there is some problem with in your jar. hope this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373550/class-not-found-exception-in-mapreduce-wordcount-job