# MapReduce code does not run in Hadoop clustering

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I have set up hadoop-1.2.1 multi node clustering . Please help me I have spend a lot of time but not understanding why no mapreduce code run. In `bashr`c file I have `export JAVA_HOME` , `export HADOOP_HOME`, `export PATH`, `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. I have tried WordCount and ProcessUnits but I have face the same problem. Now I think the code has no problem rather there is something else.

```
hadoop@hadoop:~/hadoop$ hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main hadoop/WordCount.java
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

hadoop@hadoop:~/hadoop$ jar -cf units.jar hadoop/WordCount*.class
hadoop@hadoop:~/hadoop$ hadoop jar units.jar hadoop/WordCount input_dir output_dir
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

17/03/06 02:41:48 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
17/03/06 02:41:48 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
17/03/06 02:41:49 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
17/03/06 02:41:49 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
17/03/06 02:41:49 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
17/03/06 02:41:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201703052335_0001
17/03/06 02:41:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/03/06 02:42:02 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201703052335_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hadoop.WordCount$Map
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:718)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hadoop.WordCount$Map
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:855)
    ... 8 more

17/03/06 02:42:02 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection refused (Connection refused)
17/03/06 02:42:02 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection refused (Connection refused)
17/03/06 02:42:07 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201703052335_0001_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hadoop.WordCount$Map
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:718)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hadoop.WordCount$Map
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:855)
    ... 8 more

17/03/06 02:42:07 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection refused (Connection refused)
17/03/06 02:42:07 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection refused (Connection refused)
17/03/06 02:42:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201703052335_0001_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hadoop.WordCount$Map
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:718)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hadoop.WordCount$Map
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:855)
    ... 8 more

17/03/06 02:42:12 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection refused (Connection refused)
17/03/06 02:42:12 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection refused (Connection refused)
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201703052335_0001
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=24389
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
17/03/06 02:42:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
17/03/06 02:42:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
17/03/06 02:42:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
```

WordCount

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {

   public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
     private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
     private Text word = new Text();

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       String line = value.toString();
       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
       while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
         word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
         output.collect(word, one);
       }
     }
   }

   public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       int sum = 0;
       while (values.hasNext()) {
         sum += values.next().get();
       }
       output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
     }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
     conf.setJobName("wordcount");

     conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

     conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
     conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
     conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

     conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
     conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

     JobClient.runJob(conf);
   }
}
`
```

Comment: Hadoop 1.2.1? Why? You should be using Hadoop 2.x if you want to run the latest codes. Besides that `hadoop/WordCount` is just not correct classname... You should read the official Hadoop MapReduce tutorial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class Not Found Exception in Mapreduce wordcount job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373550/class-not-found-exception-in-mapreduce-wordcount-job)

Answer (score 0):

try to add `conf.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);` 
it should add your jar-file to distributed cache.